# Plotting values of a data frame with grouping

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I have a data frame (score) that looks like this with about 20 equal participants over 2 groups:

```
PartID Group S_Base S1_score S2_score S3_score S4_score S5_score S6_score S7_score S8_score S9_score S10_score  
1   P1     1  2.0     3.5     2.0     1.5    1.5    1.50     0.75     2.0     1.0     1.5     3.00      2.5           
2   P2    2  4.0     1.0     1.0     0.0    0.00    0.00     0.0     3.0     1.0     1.0     2.00      3.0           
3   P3    2  2.5     2.0     2.5     1.0    3.0    3.0     4.0     4.0     4.0     3.0     2.00      2.0         
4   P4     1  2.0     2.0     3.0     2.0    3.0    2.50     2.0     3.0     2.5     2.5     2.00      1.0         
5   P5    2  5.0     5.0     4.0     4.0    4.00    2.00     4.0     2.0     2.0     2.0     2.00      0.0           
6   P6     1  5.0     4.0     4.0     3.0    3.0    3.0     1.0     2.0     3.0     3.5     4.00      4.0           
7   P7     1  2.5     2.0     3.0     2.0    2.00    2.50     2.5     2.0     2.5     2.0     1.00      1.0           
8   P8     1  3.0     1.0     0.5     0.5    2.00    1.0     0.5     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.00      1.0           
9   P9    2  4.0     1.0     1.0     2.0    5.00    5.00     0.0     2.0     2.0     1.0     4.0      1.0         
10  P10     1  2.5     0.0     1.0     1.0    1.50    0.00     0.0     1.5     0.0     1.5     2.00      1.0          
11  P11    2  4.5     3.0     1.0     1.0    1.00    1.00     0.5     0.5     0.5     0.5     0.75      1.5           
12  P12    2  1.5     1.5     1.0     2.0    2.00    2.5     1.5     1.0     0.5     1.0     1.50      1.0
```

I have looked online on guides using ggplot on how to plot these as line graphs with standard deviations as two groups but struggling. I believe I need to reshape my data to achieve this.

Could anyone help? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you are looking for something like this? Here, we pivot all your scores to long format, then plot all your data points so that people can see the spread and distribution of your data. We add error bars at one standard deviation and prominent red points at the mean for each group, joined by a line, all using ggplot summary functions.

```r
library(tidyverse)

score %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with('S')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(Group), y = value)) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = 'line', aes(group = 1)) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, fun.max = function(x) mean(x) + sd(x),
               fun.min = function(x) mean(x) - sd(x), geom = 'errorbar',
               width = 0.1) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = 'point', size = 4, aes(color = 'Mean'),
               alpha = 0.8) +
  geom_point(position = position_jitter(width = 0.1), 
             color = 'deepskyblue4') +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  scale_color_manual(name = NULL, values = c('red3')) +
  labs(y = 'Score', x = 'Group')
```

[image]

---

**Data frame used - taken from question**

```r
score <- structure(list(PartID = c("p1", "p2"), Group = 1:2, Base = c(2, 
4), S1_score = c(2.5, 1), S2_score = c(2, 1), S3_score = c(1.5, 
0), S4_score = c(1.75, 0), S5_score = c(1.5, 0)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2"))
```

---

**EDIT**

To have scores along the x axis and different lines and error bars for the groups, the summary statistics would need to be dodged to avoid overplotting. The result could be obtained by doing something like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

score %>%
  rename(S0_score = Base) %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with('S')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = value, group = Group, color = factor(Group))) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = 'line', aes(group = Group),
               position = position_dodge(width = 0.4), alpha = 0.5) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, fun.max = function(x) mean(x) + sd(x),
               fun.min = function(x) mean(x) - sd(x), geom = 'errorbar',
               width = 0.25, position = position_dodge(width = 0.4),
               alpha = 0.5) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = 'point', size = 4,
               alpha = 0.8, position = position_dodge(width = 0.4)) +
  geom_point(position = position_jitterdodge(dodge.width = 0.4,
                                             jitter.width = 0.4),
             alpha = 0.5) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  scale_color_manual(name = 'Group', values = c('red3', 'deepskyblue4')) +
  labs(y = 'Score', x = 'Group')
```

[image]

This required the use of some made-up data not in the question:

```r
set.seed(1)

score <- data.frame(PartID = paste0('p', 1:20),
                    Group = rep(1:2, 10),
                    Base = round(runif(20, 0, 5), 1),
                    S1_score = round(runif(20, 0, 5), 1),
                    S2_score = round(runif(20, 0, 5), 1),
                    S3_score = round(runif(20, 0, 5), 1),
                    S4_score = round(runif(20, 0, 5), 1),
                    S5_score = round(runif(20, 0, 5), 1))
```

Comment: I'm getting a "Error in UseMethod("pivot_longer") : 
  no applicable method for 'pivot_longer' applied to an object of class "function"" error message. I have installed and loaded the tidyverse library too

Comment: @user2573519 that's probably because your data frame is not called `df`. Please change that very first line of the pipe to whatever your data frame is called.

Comment: Ah thanks, that was me being stupid. Is there a way of doing this in which the x axis is S1_score, S2_ Score etc and then have two lines for each group? I'll have a go using your example too

Comment: Also does your code also take into consideration the "Base" values as I notice that in the code it only looks for values beginning with "S", I could change the name of "Base" to "S_Base" to make it easier.

Comment: @user2573519 yes, you should probably change `Base` to something like `S0_score` to get this code to work. You could also put S0, S1, S2 etc along the x axis, but you only provided two rows of data, which means there would only be one point at each score for each group, so I can't demonstrate the mean or SD without more data. I'm happy to make up a data set if you want and are unable to share your own?

Comment: Just updated the original post with some sample data. But have seen your edit and will try it out. Thanks!